# How can filter by list in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to filter a queryset by a list
I am getting  unicode data into format of 1,4,5,6 by

```
category = request.GET.getlist(category')
print type(category)



data = Leads.objects.filter(item_required__id= category )
```

then i am getting a error

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,4'
```

So how can i fix this.

```
Traceback:
File "/home/cp/Documents/envMyShopUp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/cp/Documents/envMyShopUp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/cp/Documents/myshopup/markatix/customapi/vendors.py" in CustomerRequirements
  365.      cust_leads = CustomerLeads.objects.filter(item_required__id__in= category ).values('customer_name','budget','event','posting_date','quantity','other','fb_id','image','title').order_by('-posting_date')
File "/home/cp/Documents/envMyShopUp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  127.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/cp/Documents/envMyShopUp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  679.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/cp/Documents/envMyShopUp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  697.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "/home/cp/Documents/envMyShopUp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1310.         clause, require_inner = self._add_q(where_part, self.used_aliases)
File "/home/cp/Documents/envMyShopUp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1338.                     allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
File "/home/cp/Documents/envMyShopUp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter
  1209.             condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
File "/home/cp/Documents/envMyShopUp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_lookup
  1102.                 return final_lookup(lhs, rhs)
File "/home/cp/Documents/envMyShopUp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in __init__
  105.         self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
File "/home/cp/Documents/envMyShopUp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in get_prep_lookup
  143.         return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_lookup(self.lookup_name, self.rhs)
File "/home/cp/Documents/envMyShopUp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_lookup
  729.             return [self.get_prep_value(v) for v in value]
File "/home/cp/Documents/envMyShopUp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  985.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /customapi/vendor/customer-requirements/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,4'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is not a list of separate items, it is a list containing the string `1,4`. `getlist` expects that you pass the arguments as in `category=1&category=4`

Answer (score 0):

I done some steps wrong.finally i got and found solution.

```
    category = request.GET.get('category')
l1=[]
    category_list =category.split(',')
    for i in category_list:
        a =int(i)
        l1.append(a)

cust_leads = CustomerLeads.objects.filter(item_required__id__in= l1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [`QueryDict.getlist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) to resolve query parameter lists for your request:

```
from django.http.request import QueryDict

query = QueryDict('category=1&category=2')
categories = query.getlist('category')  # -> ['1', '2']
leads = Leads.objects.filter(item_required__id__in=categories)
```

This way user can supply you a list of categories by adding them one-by-one into the query. This solution might be good enough for you.

**However**, your user (or you) might want to supply free style lists, and they might be multiple in your queries. In that case you would have to get all lists, which can be lists of primary keys, and map them to a flat list which can be used in a Django filter...

```
from itertools import chain
from django.http.request import QueryDict

query = QueryDict('categories=1,2,3&categories=4,5')
categories_strings = query.getlist('categories')  # -> ['1,2,3', '4,5']
categories = list(chain.from_iterable(
    map(lambda categories: categories.split(','), categories_strings))
)  # -> ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
leads = Leads.objects.filter(item_required__id__in=categories)
```

Luckily for us, you could easily write this into a neat little function:

```
# Your myapp/utils.py module
from itertools import chain

# Python 3.5+ type type annotated function, you can use
# this without the type annotations in Python 2.7 as well
def get_query_list(querydict: QueryDict, key: str) -> list:
    return list(chain.from_iterable(
        map(lambda query: query.split(','), querydict.getlist(key)))
    )
```

And this is how it works:

```
from django.http.request import QueryDict
from myapp.utils import get_query_list

q = QueryDict('a=1&a=2&a=3,4')
get_query_list(q, 'a')  # -> ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

You can use it from your view:

```
# Your myapp/views.py module
from myapp.utils import get_query_list

def my_view(request):
    categories = get_query_list(request.GET, 'categories')  # or 'category'
    # ...
```

This is the more verbose way instead of using a singular query parameter in place of a list and supports multiple different formats.

Add type assortions as necessary:

```
def my_view(request):
    # A nice and neat one-liner
    categories = get_query_list(request.GET, 'categories')  # or 'category'
    for item in categories:
        try:
            assert int(item)
        except ValueError:
            raise ValidationError('{} is not of correct type {}'.format(item, int))
    # Everything should be parsed and validated
    leads = Leads.objects.filter(item_required__id__in=categories)
```

This approach is often needed with Django when implementing search or generic filters.