# using django-rest-framework how query works for list fields?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, mongoengine, django-filter, restframeworkmongoengine

I'm using get_queryset with Django-REST-Framework to build APIs for my app.

I would like to know if there's a way to get this filter working

http://api/data?district=Nasik,Pune

to get all data with district "Pune" OR district "Nasik".
I've tried with

http://api/data?district=Nasik&district=Pune
but as expected it does an AND between the filters and retrieve only the Pune district (i suppose because it's the last filter).

**Here is my code :**

```
from rest_framework_mongoengine.viewsets import ModelViewSet as MongoModelViewSet
from app.serializers import *
from mongoengine.queryset.visitor import Q

class ToolViewSet(MongoModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = ToolSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset_list =Tool.objects.all()
        fruit=self.request.query_params.get("fruit")
        district=self.request.query_params.get("district")
        taluka=self.request.query_params.get("taluka")

        if fruit and district:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
            Q(fruit__icontains=fruit)
            &Q(district__icontains=district)
            )
            return queryset_list

        if fruit and taluka:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
            Q(fruit__icontains=fruit)
            &Q(taluka__icontains=taluka)
            )
            return queryset_list


        if district and taluka:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
            Q(district__icontains=district)
            &Q(taluka__icontains=taluka)
            )
            return queryset_list

        elif fruit:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
            Q(fruit__icontains=fruit)
            )
            return queryset_list

        elif district:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
            Q(district__icontains=district)
            )  
            return queryset_list

        elif taluka:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
            Q(taluka__icontains=taluka)
            )  
            return queryset_list
```

so, this code working for two different fields,

for example:

http://api/?data?fruit=Banana&district=Pune

http://api/?data?fruit=Banana&taluka=Haveli

http://api/?data?taluka=Haveli&district=Pune

all are working but,

http://api/data?district=Nasik,Pune

this is not working,
here I use  this code for "OR"

```
if district or district:
    queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
        Q(district__icontains=fruit)
        |Q(district__icontains=district)
    )
    return queryset_list
```

but it's not working, any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: I answered another question on how to resolve list of parameters recently, you might find it useful with resolving your list of filter words: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41335388/7120972. Also, you can resolve your list of querybuilders (Q objects) in an easiers fashion: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26613698/7120972.

Comment: i have written a django search engine library to solve the case like yours, may be you can have a look at it...https://github.com/enix223/djolar..

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the new filter for this.
As reference to django-filter issue https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/137

```
from django_filters import Filter
from django_filters.fields import Lookup

class ListFilter( Filter ):
  def filter( self, qs, value ):
    return super( ListFilter, self ).filter( qs, Lookup( value.split( u"," ), "in") )
```

Have you got both the value Pune & Nashik in get_queryset method ?

Note: - Updated

Cloud you please try this code in order to get both the district value.

```
fields = request.query_params.get('district ')
    if fields:
        fields = fields.split(',')
        dis = set(fields)  # dis is a set of all request param value.
```

Comment: I used this code you gave me earlier, but I want to write this using get_query set

Comment: I am not using django restframework backend filter. I want to write in code.